# How do I calculate fuzz ratio between two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

Getting started with Pandas.

```
I have two columns:
A                     B
Something             Something Else
Everything            Evythn
Someone               Cat
Everyone              Evr1
```

I want to calculate fuzz ratio for each row between the two columns so the output would be something like this:

```
A                     B                  Ratio
Something             Something Else     12
Everything            Evythn             14
Someone               Cat                10
Everyone              Evr1               20
```

How would I be able to accomplish this? Both the columns are in the same df.

Comment: First, how are you calculating fuzz ratio between two strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use lambda function with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df['Ratio'] = df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.A, x.B), axis=1)
#alternative  with list comprehension
#df['Ratio'] = [fuzz.ratio(a, b) for a,b in zip(df.A, df.B)]
print (df)
            A               B  Ratio
0   Something  Something Else     78
1  Everything          Evythn     75
2     Someone             Cat      0
3    Everyone            Evr1     50
```

EDIT:

If possible some missing values in columns it failed, so added [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
print (df)
            A               B
0   Something  Something Else
1  Everything             NaN
2     Someone             Cat
3    Everyone            Evr1

from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df['Ratio'] = df.dropna(subset=['A', 'B']).apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.A, x.B), axis=1)
print (df)
            A               B  Ratio
0   Something  Something Else   78.0
1  Everything             NaN    NaN
2     Someone             Cat    0.0
3    Everyone            Evr1   50.0
```

Comment: object of type float as no len(). i'm getting this when i replace A and B with the columns from the df

Comment: @balkotdude can you try `df['Ratio'] = df. dropna(subset=['A', 'B']).apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.A, x.B), axis=1)`?